# Can you get messages to the dead-letter-queue with Azure Functions (Typescript) using the supplied Service Bus Trigger?

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

When looking at [microsofts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-typescript) for service bus triggers for Azure Functions using Typescript (or any non c# language), it looks to me like it is impossible to utilize the DLQ functionality of the servicebus (rendering large parts of the reason why I want to use ServiceBus unusable).

Is there some way to override the innate functionality and place messages on the DLQ manually if my function cannot process them? Seems like the standard now is to just abandon the message ‍♂️

Using timer-trigger and just implementing the service-bus library by standard is an option, but that takes away some of the event-driven architecture behind this.

Maybe using a durable function? (although that defeats the purpose of using functions for this -> i can just write a small statefull service instead)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only the .NET Function workers (both in-proc and isolated) are able to bind to the `ServiceBusMessageActions` parameter needed to explicitly dead-letter messages.  The only way for other language workers to dead-letter a message is for it to fail to process enough times that the delivery count is exceeded or one of [the other service-side DLQ actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues#moving-messages-to-the-dlq) is triggered.

Work is planned to bring the message actions functionality to the other language workers, but there is not yet a public timeline to share.